# How can I speed up my R code when multiplying across tables?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, coding-efficiency

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
dtA <- data.table(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, D = 7:9)
dtB <- data.table(id = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), multi = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))


for(COL in c("A", "B", "D")) {
  dtA[, (COL) := get(COL) * dtB[id == COL, multi]] 
}
```

I need to multiply the columns in dtA by the multiplier using the id column in dtB to identify which column to multiply by which factor. I can do it with a for loop but it is very slow. I would love any recommendations on how to improve efficiency. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is a little faster than your method

```
vec <- dtB[colnames(dtA), multi, on = 'id']
dtA <- as.data.table(mapply(function(x,y) x*y, dtA, vec, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

Can't really see where you could get a significant speed up though, as I don't think you are doing anything particularly wasteful in your attempt.

EDIT:

This is about 50% faster again on larger examples

```
cn <- colnames(dtA)
dtA[,(cn) := mapply(function(x,y) x*y, dtA, dtB[cn, multi, on = 'id'], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you may be best served by using a library designed to compute products quickly then storing the results in a data.table or other formats. For example, 'Rfast' is optimized for numerical computations on matrices. R 'data.table' is excellent at storage and retrieval of large data tables but by default stores as (R) lists:

```
library(data.table)
library(Rfast)

# https://rdrr.io/cran/Rfast/man/
# https://github.com/RfastOfficial/Rfast
# install.packages("Rfast")

x <- matrnorm(10^7,2)

dt <- setnames(as.data.table(cbind(x,prod=rowprods(x))),c("mult1","mult2","prod"))[]

object.size(dt)
240001544 bytes
dt
               mult1      mult2       prod
       1: -0.8085044 -1.9285537  1.5592442
       2: -1.5677905 -1.5577447  2.4422173
       3:  0.5049556 -0.2790959 -0.1409310
       4: -0.4603246  0.7289480 -0.3355527
       5:  1.4131808 -1.0857271 -1.5343287
      ---                                 
 9999996:  0.2373198 -0.7700162 -0.1827401
 9999997: -1.4357042  0.9946241 -1.4279859
 9999998:  1.1464551  0.1137755  0.1304385
 9999999:  0.3204307 -0.9189214 -0.2944506
10000000:  1.5800871 -1.3029509 -2.0587759

x <- matrnorm(10^7,2)
system.time(setnames(as.data.table(cbind(x,prod=rowprods(x))),c("mult1","mult2","prod"))[])
       user  system elapsed 
       0.12    0.08    0.21
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a `data.table` approach.. probably not the nnicest way.. but it gets the job done.

```
library( data.table )
#melt dtA to long format
dtA.melt <- melt( dtA, measure.vars = names(dtA), variable.factor = FALSE)
#set integers to numeric
dtA.melt[, value := as.numeric(value)]
#update the value column using a join
dtA.melt[ dtB, value := as.numeric(value) * i.multi, on = .(variable = id)]
#and bind back the columns
do.call( cbind, split( dtA.melt, by = "variable", keep.by = FALSE ) )

#    A.value B.value D.value
# 1:     0.1     0.8     2.8
# 2:     0.2     1.0     3.2
# 3:     0.3     1.2     3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach

```
as.data.table(t(t(dtA) * with(dtB, multi[match(names(dtA),id)])))
```

which gives

```
     A   B   D
1: 0.1 0.8 2.8
2: 0.2 1.0 3.2
3: 0.3 1.2 3.6
```